# Installing MXNET on Python 3.9 (3.7>)

Tags: python, numpy, installation, libraries, mxnet

I am looking for ways to install the `mxnet` library on `python 3.9` as due to its `numpy` dependency that supports only `numpy 1.16 to 1.18` which isnt cross compatible with `Python 3.9` but only supports `Python 3.6`.

I have attempted to install `numpy 1.18` before installing `mxnet` but what ends up happening is that it gets stuck in installing the wheel.

Would there be a manual process to get this installed in my virtual environment?

Please let me know if you require additional information.